# Всегда ли является ли содержимое {...} объектом?

Tags: javascript, ооп

Всегда ли является ли содержимое `{...}` объектом?

Например в случае с `function(){...}` или `if (){...}`?

Comment: Нет. Оба этих примера это блоки кода. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA

Comment: В функции вряд ли это блок кода, не? нельзя же записать функцию одного оператора без скобок..

Comment: Да, у функции это просто такой синтаксис, а не блок кода. Как и в try/catch. Тем не менее это прямой ответ на вопрос в заголовке: не всегда. И даже чаще всего нет.

Comment: @vp_arth, в случае стрелочной функции - можно. Но в целом, Вы правы. "Поведение" фигурных скобок варьируется в зависимости от контекста... как и в случае круглых скобок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сама по себе конструкция `{...}` в Си-подобных языках,  это блок кода, который служит для отделения логики внутри от логики снаружи, соответсвенно у таких блоков своя область видимости. В объектах, это тоже служит отдалением внутриней логики от внешней, то есть мы присваиваем имени объект, а заполнения и его логика находиться внутри блока кода.